# Find the probability that no boy sits between two girls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> **Example.** Five boys and three girls are seated at random in a row. Find the probability that no boy sits between two girls.
>   **Solution.**: $\quad n(s) = 8!$
>   $n$(E) = The number of arrangement of $5$ boys and $3$ girls when $3$ girls are consecutive = $6!\times 3!$
>   $$\therefore\quad \text{Required probability } = \frac{6!\times 3!}{8!} = \frac{3}{28}.$$

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSJGL.png)

I think the given answer is incorrect as their might be a situation like GGBBBBBG where no boy is between two girls and it is not counted in favourable ways. According to me, required ways can be counted using total - non favourable (N.F.) ways. I calculated N. F. using the logic that at least one GBG group should not be counted.

N.F.= $5C1 * 3C2 * 2 * 6!$

Total = $8!$

My ans = $13/28$

Please tell if I'm correct.

Comment: In GGBBBBBG there are $5$ boys sitting between (the same) $2$ girls.

Comment: It's an interpretation thing.  You are trying to find the probability that *no boy is **adjacent** to two girls*.  That's not the same thing as *no boy is **between** two girls*, if you read "between" as "being somewhere to the left of one girl and somewhere to  the right of the other".

Comment: I counted thinking that no two boy is between EXACTLY two girls .

Comment: This isn’t maths. It’s guessing what exactly the person asking wants to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you arrange as GGBBBBBG, there will be $5$ boys sitting between $2$ girls, but the question demands "no boys between 2 girls"

You are not puzzled by the sum, it's the language of the question which is driving you to wrong way.  Don't be upset. I also get puzzled. Recently, in an exam I didn't attend an easy probability sum for its puzzling words and did another sum which was a page long, lol.

You can do it as mentioned below:

First make all 5 boys seated, which can be done in $5!$ ways. Now you can see 6 gaps created.......(1)

$$\underline{} B \underline{} B \underline{} B \underline{} B \underline{} B \underline{}$$

Now you take group of girls together. Consider GGG.  You can make this group seat in any one of the $6$ gaps, so there are $6$ ways and you can arrange the $3$ girls among themselves in $3!$ ways , so here total no. of ways $6 \cdot 3!$
........................(2)

From (1) and (2) you can say no. of ways $= 5! \cdot 6 \cdot 3!$

If there's no restriction, then total no. of ways $=8!$.

Divide to get the probability
$$\frac{5! \cdot 6 \cdot 3!}{8!} = \frac{6! \cdot 3!}{8!} = \frac{6}{8 \cdot 7} = \frac{3}{28}$$

!Answer!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.